# JQuery: Return TBODY html except for rows that don't have class=hidden

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a table for example as follows:

```
<table>
 <thead>
   .....
 </thead>
 <tbody id="rptBody"> 
   <tr><td>Row 1</td></tr>
   <tr class="hidden"><td>Row 2</td></tr>
   <tr class="hidden"><td>Row 3</td></tr>
   <tr><td>Row 4</td></tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to pass $('#rptBody').html() to another function that will print the rows selected (i.e. where class <> hidden).

I tried:

```
$('#rptBody tr:not(.hidden)').html()
```

But that returns just the columns from the first non-hidden row.  How can I filter the tbody.html to just include the non-hidden rows?

Comment: you need to use `filter` function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think if you want the html (rather than just a set of matching dom objects) you probably need to clone the original. Something like this

```js
x=$('#rptBody').clone();
x.find('.hidden').remove();
alert(x.html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
 <thead>
 </thead>
 <tbody id="rptBody"> 
   <tr><td>Row 1</td></tr>
   <tr class="hidden"><td>Row 2</td></tr>
   <tr class="hidden"><td>Row 3</td></tr>
   <tr><td>Row 4</td></tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks Chris, I've been trying to work with this, because it makes complete sense it should work but when I alert the html I see that the rows are not removed which doesn't make sense at all. I still see all the <tr class="hidden"> begin returned, very strange.

Comment: I've improved the code. There's probably a nicer way to do it, but I was using remove() wrongly previously. This version works I think.

Answer (score 0):

You should use **filter** then clone. As filter has less **load** then clone whole html.

```js
var matching = $('#rptBody tr').filter(function(){
                   return $(this).not('.hidden');
                });

alert(matching.html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
 <thead>
 </thead>
 <tbody id="rptBody"> 
   <tr><td>Row 1</td></tr>
   <tr class="hidden"><td>Row 2</td></tr>
   <tr class="hidden"><td>Row 3</td></tr>
   <tr><td>Row 4</td></tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did try that but it didn't work.  I did: 
           var matching = $('#rptBody tr').filter(function () {
                return $(this).hasClass('.hidden').length == 0;
            });

            alert(matching.html()); 

But the return is "undefined" instead of the html string.

Comment: @BrianEdwards please run snippet.

Comment: Thanks, but it only returned "Row 1"  Why didn't it also return "Row 4"?   The other problem is it only returns the "<td>" and not the "<tr><td>".

Answer (score 0):

It's important to understand, what do you want to do then :)

$('#rptBody tr:not(.hidden)')

returns jQuery array of objects.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#rptBody tr').each(function(){
    if ( $(this).hasClass('hidden') ) 
        {
            console.log( $(this).html() );
        }
    else 
        {
            console.log('Nope.');
        }
})
```

This will give you ability to control both cases :).

Comment: This only gives the html of the tr elements, not the whole table. So although it might be useful, it isn't really what was being asked for.

Comment: "I want to pass $('#rptBody').html() to another function **that will print the rows selected** ". Really?